# Having issues with Attribute Error using pub_date_pretty

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, bootstrap-modal

Trying to do this code to make time appear with less info but, I'm getting an Error

```
def pub_date_pretty(self):
   return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')
```

```
def pub_date_pretty(self):
    return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')
```

[image1updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4dV3.png) [code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhm4i.png) [code 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKPJI.png) [CMD ERROR HELP!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOkPJ.png)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow, do not put pictures of code instead paste the code in the question so that other community readers can understand your problem easily. You might wanna read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Oh, soory Rorat im new so, I did not know, I thought it would be easy and less mess i think the bigger the code the hard to read because it take a bit more time.

Comment: You should only put the relevant code segment in the code (need not put the whole code). Reading this might help [How to create Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a misspelling error. In your first picture I see the Blog model and it has a field named **pub_data** but everywhere else you are referring to it as **pub_date**. (see the last letter)
So, rename the field in the model, make your migrations and run them.

Comment: I see, I changed from data to date but, now I'm getting a programming error and yes i did migrate   ProgrammingError
Exception Value: 
column blog_blog.pub_date does not exist

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer `python manage.py makemigrations 
                     [y]
                     python manage.py migrate 
since I'm new it would have saved me lot a time because, I thought it was

```
                  git add -A
                  git commit -m
```